# how to port a project built in eclipse into a phonegap build project?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

My original project was built in Eclipse.  I have created a new project using CLI for phonegap, using cordova create...., cordova platform add android, cordova build.  This works fine but now I have no idea what to do with this cordova project.  The class extends CordovaActivity, the manifest is completely different.
Someone please guide me.  What do I have to do to convert my original project, developed in Eclipse 4.2, into a cordova project?
Thank you. I'm on a windows 8 machine.

Comment: PhoneGap is not a tool for converting native apps. PhoneGap provides a simple native application with a WebView as the main view. You then use HTML/CSS/JS to build your application just like you would a website. You are able to use/create plugins for PhoneGap that make use of native code, but you still need HTML/CSS/JS to do that.

Comment: Ok.  so it uses a webview as a main view.  is that why you use super.loadURL(Config.getStartUrl()); instead of setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity)?

Comment: Also, the www folder in PhoneGapSample application contains three folders: css, img, js.  Can I copy my .java files from my original app created in Eclipse into the www>js folder in cordova app?

Comment: To the firs question: yes, this why `super.loadUrl`. To the second: no, java files cannot be run by a webview. I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with PhoneGap. With PhoneGap you don't need to touch any native code to build an application. You just use HTML, CSS and JavaScript to build your application. You only use Java or Objective-C if you are going to create a plugin for PhoneGap.

Comment: Thank you Dawson.  But aren't the activities in eclipse written in javascript?

Comment: I just found this...http://tboxmy.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-android-app-with-phonegap-and.html

Comment: Java and Javascript are two different languages. You can use Eclipse to build your phonegap project in, but you don't write any native android code to build a phonegap application. So if you already have a  working Android application you can't just port that to PhoneGap. You would have to rebuild the UI using HTML/CSS/JS and unlike an adroid application you don't have multiple activities and views, you only have a main activity and one webview. You use JS and HTML to create sudo views in the webview.

Comment: Thank you, you've been a big help.  Unfortunately it sounds like you're saying I have to start from the beginning and learn how to program for phonegap/cordova in Eclipse.  This seems misleading because phonegap build makes it seem as if you can simply upload your code and it will do all the work of preparing your code for different platforms.

Comment: The phonegap build service allows you to upload as little as 1 index.html file and 1 config.xml file and then will build your application in any platform supported. But you have to start with HTML, it cannot come from another existing native application.

Comment: so what about features like google text to speech and google speech recognition?  I built apps with dreamweaver a long time ago and understand the concept of CCS, HTML, Javascript but it seems like that's a lot different than building with Eclipse and using findViewById, R.id.textview1, xml layouts, etc.  How would you include a text to speech function that would apply for apple and android?

Comment: For any native functionality you use PhoneGap plugins, that is the core of what phonegap is. A plugin consists of native code and javascript, and phonegap provides a link between the two. You call plugin methods with javascript that route to native code and the native code sends a callback to the javascript.